# After update to IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 ::ng-deep is deprecated

Tags: css, angular, intellij-idea, sass, angular-material

As the headline says, I updated the version of IntelliJ and now the angular material selector ::ng-deep is showing me as deprecated.

Example:

```
<mat-form-field class="register-custom-select">
 <mat-select formControlName="gender" required>
   <mat-option class="register-custom-option" *ngFor="let gender of genders 
   [value]="gender.genderValue">
    {{ gender.genderValue }}
   </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>

::ng-deep .register-custom-select .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: #838383;
}
```

What do I need to change to make the selector no longer deprecated and still have the style?

Comment: See if this helps: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors

Comment: I have already done that. Since ::ng-deep is documented as valid

Comment: IntelliJ marks ::ng-deep as deprecated, because it is.

Comment: it's indeed deprecated, see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

For me using globale style resolve this

In your style.css yu can add

```
.register-custom-select .mat-form-field-underline { 
background-color: #838383!important; 
}
```